# Why is my jQuery event listener not running upon app startup?

Tags: javascript, flask, jquery-events, html-input

I'm working on making a script that detects if a checkbox with id "chapterex" is checked, and updates the page accordingly if it is: if it is not checked, add the multiple attribute to the file upload. Otherwise, do NOT include the multiple attribute. The script runs, but seemingly does not perform its intended action.

=====js file=====

```
function check() {
  let checked = $("#chapterex").is(':checked');
  console.log("checked", checked);
  let inner_html = "<span><strong>Step 2:</strong></span>" +
  "<label for='myfile'>Select a file</label>" +
  "<input type='file' id='letter' name='letter'>" +
  "</div>";
  let inner_html_multiple = "<span><strong>Step 2:</strong></span>" +
  "<label for='myfile'>Select a file</label>" +
  "<input type='file' 'id='letter' name='letter' multiple>" +
  "</div>";
  if (checked) {
    console.log("checked in if");
    $('#file_field').replaceWith(inner_html);
  } else {
    console.log("not checked, in else");
    $('#file_field').replaceWith(inner_html_multiple);
  }
}
check();
console.log("hi successfully attached");
$('#chapterex').on('change', check);
```

=======html file=====

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12" style="padding-left:0px">
            <span><strong>Step 1:</strong></span>
            <label for="chapter">Text</label>
            <span><input type="checkbox" id="chapterex" name="chapterex"><span>&nbsp;Yes</span></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-sm-12" style="padding-left:0px" id="file_field">
            <!-- <span><strong>Step 2:</strong></span>
            <label for="myfile">Select a file</label>
            <input type="file" id="letter" name="letter"> -->
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-sm-12" style="padding-left:0px">
            <span><strong>Step 3:</strong></span>
```

console info:

```
-checked false
-not checked, in else
-hi successfully attached
```

When I add the event listener in console, it works. Based on the console output it is running everything, but seemingly not attaching the HTML. I'm not sure if this matters, but I am using Python's Flask library and this is a script hosted in a different directory. It's obviously running though, so I doubt that's the source of any issue.

Another problem I'm having is that even when it attaches correctly, it seems I'm unable to attach multiple files. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I changed replaceWith() to html(), but it still has the same behavior. It's also worth noting that check does not work by default, I have to call it in console. This is not the desired behavior. Any ideas on why that might be?

Comment: I figured out the issue: I was loading the script before the HTML rendered the file_field ID. As a result, the event handler attached to nothing. Any ideas on why the multiple attribute isn't working though?

Comment: `multiple` attribute works well, run the snippet in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your code is, that you're removing `#file_field` element when you're calling `check` for the first time. Then, when `change` event calls `check`, the element is not found, and seemingly nothing happens.

It's notable, that `$('#file_field')` returns a jQuery object even when no elements was found, and calling `replaceWith` of the "empty" jQuery object doesn't trigger any errors.

Wrap your code into `$(document).ready(function () {your code here});` to make sure all the elements exist at the time the code runs, and use `.html()` instead of `.replaceWith()`.

```js
function check() {
  let checked = $("#chapterex").is(':checked');
  let inner_html = "<span><strong>Step 2:</strong></span>" +
    "<label for='letter'>Select a file </label>" +
    "<input type='file' id='letter' name='letter'>" +
    "</div>";
  let inner_html_multiple = "<span><strong>Step 2:</strong></span>" +
    "<label for='letter'>Select multiple files </label>" +
    "<input type='file' id='letter' name='letter' multiple>" +
    "</div>";
  if (checked) {
    $('#file_field').html(inner_html);
  } else {
    $('#file_field').html(inner_html_multiple);
  }
}
check();
$('#chapterex').on('change', check);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-sm-12" style="padding-left:0px">
  <span><strong>Step 1:</strong></span>
  <label for="chapter">Text</label>
  <span><input type="checkbox" id="chapterex" name="chapterex"><span>&nbsp;Yes</span></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-12" style="padding-left:0px" id="file_field"></div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-12" style="padding-left:0px">
  <span><strong>Step 3:</strong></span>
</div>
```

There was also a typo in `inner_html_multiple`, `id` attribute of `label` tag was preceded by an extra single quote, that caused the dead label.